# how to create a nested [String: Anyobject] in Swift?

Tags: json, swift4, alamofire, nsdictionary

I am creating a nested `[String: AnyObject]` in the following way:

```
let info = ["para1": test(String) as AnyObject,
            "para2": test(String) as AnyObject]

let paramater = ["para_info": info([String: AnyObject]) as AnyObject,
                    "product_id": test(String) as AnyObject,
                    "amount": test(String) as AnyObject]
```

using the **parameter** where **info** is a nested `[String: AnyObject]` but requesting this in the following way as a **POST** request is treating as an **Array with nested Dictionary**:

```
try JSONEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, withJSONObject: parameters)
```

So, am I creating the nested `[String: AnyObject]` correctly?

Comment: Why `AnyObject` at all? In Swift 3+ all value types like `String` or `Int` are `Any`. This avoids the ugly bridge cast.

Comment: but I am using `AnyObject` for all other API's and they are working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you explicitly want it as [String:AnyObject]:

```
  var dict: [String:AnyObject] = ["messageCode":"API_200" as AnyObject,
                                "data": ["activities": [["action":1,
                                                         "state":1]],
                                         "messages": [["body":"hi"]]] as AnyObject,
                                "message": "" as AnyObject]
```

Basically all the root values should be typecasted as AnyObject

Or the long way:

```
   //Activities is as Array of dictionary with Int values
var activities = [[String:Int]]()
activities.append(["action": 1,
                   "state": 1])

//Messages is an Array of string
var messages = [[String:String]]()
messages.append(["body" : "hi"])

//Data is dictionary containing activities and messages
var data = [String:Any]()
data["activities"] = activities
data["messages"] = messages

//Finally your base dictionary
var dict = [String:AnyObject]()
dict["messageCode"] = "API_200" as AnyObject
dict["data"] = data as AnyObject
dict["message"] = "" as AnyObject
print(dict)
```